# Frank-Wolfe Algorithm

Tags: java, algorithm

Do you know any implementation, (java) to solve non linear programming with this algorithm? Could you explain that algorithm, or the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wikipedia has some pretty good [pseudocode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frank%E2%80%93Wolfe_algorithm).

Comment: well I know, but it eill be useful a java implementation or a java applet to understand it better.
I know it uses partials, and an aprox using simplex, then attacks the problem...

Comment: Have you tried writing something yet that you have a problem with?

Comment: some partial diferentation, some libraries?